# How to call a constructor inside a method?

Tags: java, class, methods, syntax, constructor

I have a constructor called Student:

```
public Student(String suppliedFirstName, String suppliedLastName, int suppliedAge) {
    firstName = suppliedFirstName;
    lastName = suppliedLastName;
age = suppliedAge;
        }
```

A constructor called Section:

```
public Section(String inName, int inMaximum) {
    name = inName;
maximumStudents = inMaximum;

List<Student> studentRoster = new ArrayList<Student>();
List<Student> studentWaitList = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

And a method that I want to add students to the list studentRoster by calling the Student Constructor:

```
public void signUp(Student inStudent()) {
    if(studentRoster.size() == maximumStudents) {
studentWaitList.add(inStudent());
return;
}

studentRoster.add(inStudent());

}
```

I keep getting errors when trying to do this saying I haven't completed the MethodDeclaration. What is the proper syntax to do this properly?

Comment: You don't put parentheses after a variable name like you're doing in "Student inStudent()". Also your studentRoster and studentWaitList are local variables which will disappear as soon as the Section constructor finishes.

Comment: You will need to declare your studentRoster and studentWaitList lists as instance variables. Currently they are local variables to your Section constructor, and you will lose access to them after the constructor finishes. If they are instance variables already, you are shadowing them and not initializing them in the constructor.

Comment: Change `public void signUp(Student inStudent()) {` to `public void signUp(Student inStudent) {` - that will take away that error.  Of course, your code has many other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void signUp(Student inStudent) {
   if (studentRoster.size() == maximumStudents) {
       studentWaitList.add(inStudent);
       return;
   }
   studentRoster.add(inStudent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an `Student` instance to `signUp()` method, it should be:

```
public void signUp(Student inStudent) {
    if(studentRoster.size() == maximumStudents) {
        studentWaitList.add(inStudent);
        return;
    }
    studentRoster.add(inStudent);
}
```

then you will have to call the method like:

```
signUp(new Student(...));
```

or

```
Student lastStudent = new Student(...);
signUp(lastStudent);
```

**Note** that doing this, the `Student` instance *is being initialized* before it is passed to the method `signUp`. In other words, the constructor is being called before it is passed to the method.

Also, you have to declare `studentRoster` and `studentWaitList` as fields of the class `Section`. In

```
public Section(String inName, int inMaximum) {
    name = inName;
    maximumStudents = inMaximum;
    List<Student> studentRoster = new ArrayList<Student>();
    List<Student> studentWaitList = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

they are being declared as *local variables*. You may want to do this instead:

```
public class Section {
    List<Student> studentRoste;
    List<Student> studentWaitList;

    public Section(String inName, int inMaximum) {
        name = inName;
        maximumStudents = inMaximum;
        studentRoster = new ArrayList<Student>(); // INITIALIZE
        studentWaitList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }
}
```

Comment: In that last wee block, you seem to be initialising those lists twice each.